# JS Prototype AJAX Post Request not being sent

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, prototypejs

I am trying to use prototype within my application to send some json data to my servlet and have it processed. Here is my ajax request:

```
            var dataToSend = getFormDataAsJSONString();
        alert(dataToSend);
        new Ajax.Request('GetExpenses', {
            method: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            postBody: 'data='+dataToSend,
            asynchronous: true,
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                parseReturnedExpenses(getPeriod(), transport.responseText);
            },
            onFailure: function(req) {
                alert('unable to send ajax post.');
            },
            onComplete: function(req) {
                alert('request completed');
            }
        });
```

I have System.out.println() statements in my doPost() servlet method just to see if the method is being called, and it is never being called. I also put print outs in the onfailure and oncomplete functions, and im not seeing either of those.

My dataToSend string looks good, so I'm not sure what I'm missing. I have my GetExpenses Servlet defined in my web.xml file, so I'm not sure whats going on. Does anyone see anything obvious with my code that is an error?

My GET request is working perfectly:

```
    new Ajax.Request("GetExpenses",
        {method: 'get',
            parameters: {'period': period},
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                parseReturnedExpenses(period, json);
            }});
```

Comment: Try removing `contentType` from your POST call and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Have you try to remove postBody and add parameters as in the get method?

Comment: Are you posting on a server in the same Domain ?